# I am having problems with getting current_user data

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am in the activeadmin dashboard. I am trying to only show customers of the current_user but I get an error `undefined local variable or method`current_user'`

here is my code for the dashboard:

```
section "Recent Customers" do
table_for Customer.owned_by(current_user).limit(5) do
  column "Name" do |customer| 
    link_to customer.name, admin_customers_path(customer)
  end
  column :phone
  column :email, :sortable => :email do |customer|
    link_to customer.email, "mailto:#{customer.email}"
  end
end
strong { link_to "View All Customers", admin_customers_path }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

in active_admin try `current_admin_user`

Comment: that gives me an error that looks like this: undefined method `owned_by'

Comment: did you specify the `config.current_user_method = :current_admin_user` in ` config/initializers/active_admin.rb` see: http://www.activeadmin.info/docs/1-general-configuration.html#authentication